# Blaze Plan. Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When trying to send mail with `nodemailer` library inside Firebase Cloud Function. I'm getting error:

`Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions`

I'm on Blaze (Pay as you go) plan.

Comment: The error message is explicitly disagrees with your perception of the billing status. If you just set up the billing account, give it a few hours to propagate (should usually not be needed, but sometimes it does). If the problem persists after that, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting the billing status of your project.

Comment: I'm on blaze for over year, so the problem is somewhere else I guess. I've send ticket as you suggested . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have same errors recently due to an expirated card, so i replace with fresh new card but errors persist `Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions`

So i revert to `Spark plan` and return to `Blaze Plan`

After that all it's working